# GridGain Out of Memory Exception: Unable to create new native thread

Tags: out-of-memory, redhat, gridgain

I'm trying to create more then 2 instances of Grid Gain (Just by running the shell script) in Red Hat Release 6.5 (Santiago), but i get the following error when i try to run the shell script a 3rd time:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.prestartAllCoreThreads(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1604)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start0(GridGainEx.java:1507)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx$GridNamedInstance.start(GridGainEx.java:1289)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start0(GridGainEx.java:832)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:759)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:677)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:524)
at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:494)
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:314)
at org.gridgain.grid.startup.cmdline.GridCommandLineStartup.main(GridCommandLineStartup.java:293)
```

I have set ulimit -n 4096 but still no joy

The box has 64GB of memory - ample amount to run more then 2 instances of GridGain

Can anyone help with this error? are there any configuration changes i can make in Red Hat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are running out of allowed number of user processes. We have encountered the same issue on our CentOs servers and setting `ulimit -u 10240` helped.

Comment: That did it! The ulimit -u was set to 1024, i increased it and it works. Thanks for your help!